# Why is this recursion terminating (correctly) by rounding down the decimals to integers?

Tags: ruby, recursion

How is n being rounded down to integers in this example so that the terminators are effective??

For example with wonky_coins(5), the next round of recursion should call for wonky_coins(2.5), wonky_coins(1.666) and wonky_coins(1.25), correct???

```
def wonky_coins(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  return 3 if n == 1

  return wonky_coins(n / 2) + wonky_coins(n / 3) + wonky_coins(n / 4)
end
```

wonky_coins(5) == 11

Round 1: [2, 1, 1]

Round 2: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Round 3: [[[0, 0, 0], 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `wonky_coins(5.0)` !

In short, Ruby interprets `/` as integer division if both operands are `Fixnum` type.

If one or other of the operands is a `Float` then the result will be a `Float`, with the associated precision (and matching what you expected to see when you looked at the example code in the question).

This can catch you out sometimes. Often when you are generating ratios between values that might be integers, you don't want this behaviour, and may need to use defensive code like this:

```
ratio = x.to_f / y
```

which forces at least one of the operands to be `Float`, just in case.

Also, you will quite often see `Float` literals specified like this:

```
ONE_THIRD = 1.0 / 3
```

because `1 / 3 == 0`.

Comment: Beauuuutiful. Thank you so much! You just saved me a world of [future] confusion!